# Paypal API receipt confusion

Tags: php, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using the Paypal PHP Rest API. I am trying to make my response display the transaction ID and the amount they paid using the echo's, but I can't figure out how to do it. This is my code so far.

```
<?php

require '/start.php';

use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution;

    if ($_GET['success'] === "false") {
        header("Location: /home");
        die('Payment was canceled.');
    }

    if(!isset($_GET['success'], $_GET['paymentId'], $_GET['PayerID'])){
        header("Location: /home");
        die('You are missing fields!');
    }


    $paymentID = $_GET['paymentId'];
    $payerId = $_GET['PayerID'];

    $payment = Payment::get($paymentID, $apiContext);

    $execute = new PaymentExecution();
    $execute->setPayerId($payerId);

    try{
        $result = $payment->execute($execute, $apiContext);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        header("Location: /home");
        die('The authorization code has expired.');
    }

echo "<!DOCTYPE html>\n";
echo "<head>\n";
echo "  <title>PureGaming\n";
echo "  </title>\n";
echo "  <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n";
echo "  <meta name=\"author\" content=\"PureGaming\">\n";
echo "  <meta name=\"description\" content=\"PureGaming is a Arma 2/3 Life community project\">\n";
echo "  <link rel=\"shortcut icon\" href=\"/favicon.ico\">\n";
echo "  <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"/css/googletext.css\">\n";
echo "  <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/css/global.css\">\n";
echo "  <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/css/donate/donate.css\">\n";
echo "  <script src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js\">\n";
echo "  </script>\n";
echo "</head>\n";
echo "<body>\n";
echo "  <div class=\"nav-container\">\n";
echo "    <div class=\"nav-header\">\n";
echo "      <a class=\"nav-header-title\" href=\"/home\">PureGaming\n";
echo "      </a>\n";
echo "      <a class=\"btn btn-primary btn-reportbug\" href=\"/bugreport\" target=\"_blank\">Report a bug\n";
echo "      </a>\n";
echo "    </div>\n";
echo "  </div>\n";
echo "  <div class=\"page-content\" id=\"page-content\" style=\"opacity: 1;\">\n";
echo "    <div class=\"tab-content\" id=\"tabcontent-donate\">\n";
echo "      <div class=\"donate-tab\">\n";
echo "        <img src=\"/images/pgemblem\" style=\"border-radius: 100%; width: 128px; height: 128px;\">\n";
echo "        <h1>Thank you so much!\n";
echo "        </h1>\n";
echo "        <h2>We can't thank you enough for the donation. Every donation is used for the PureGaming community and \n";
echo "          <b>only\n";
echo "          </b> the PureGaming community. After you leave this page, its authorization token will expire. We do currently have a limited-refund policy. Only in certain situations that the owners think are applicable, a refund will be issued. Your receipt should have been sent to the email that was used in the payment by Paypal themselves.\n";
echo "        </h2>\n";
echo "        <a class=\"paypal-link\" id=\"donate-btn\" href=\"/home\">Home\n";
echo "        </a>\n";
echo "      </div>\n";
echo "    </div>\n";
echo "  </div>\n";
echo "  <div class=\"footer\">\n";
echo "    Copyright &copy; 2016 PureGaming\n";
echo "  </div>\n";
echo "</body>\n";
?>
```

Does anyone know how I would do this and make it display the amount they paid and the transaction ID from the order? The echo part of the code only shows after they paid.

Comment: In which way does it fail?

Comment: what does `$response` returns?